# Wp-Ecommerce & Internet Explorer Checkout Email Validation

Tags: internet-explorer, wordpress

So I'm using WP-Ecommerce Version 3.8.8.5.
The site has been live for months and I've just realized that no emails will validate whatsoever on checkout when using IE.

I even attempted removing the preg match check from the includes => ajax.functions.php file and still receive an error thus not allowing anyone on IE to purchase any of our products.

I'm using the default checkout form and the field causing grief is the billingemail input.
The fact that I've removed the validation check on this field yet it still won't validate makes me think there must be a naming issue somewhere.

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to why the email validation script will not work on Internet Explorer yet works exactly as expected on every other browser I've tested? Tested IE version 8 & 9.

------Edit----------
So I've unchecked Mandatory field from the admin and I can now process transactions via IE but it doesn't still doesn't save the email info as part of the order in IE so I'm pretty sure it is a naming issue although still uncertain of how to fix.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So incase anyone else ever has a similar problem here is the solution that fixed it for me.
In the theme file wpsc-shopping_cart_page.php I just removed the following code and everything works in IE now.

```
}elseif( $wpsc_checkout->checkout_item->unique_name == 'billingemail'){ ?>
<?php $email_markup =
"
" . __('Enter your email address', 'wpsc') . "
" . wpsc_checkout_form_field();
if(wpsc_the_checkout_item_error() != '')
$email_markup .= "" . wpsc_the_checkout_item_error() . "";
$email_markup .= "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am at version 3.8.11.1 and this is still the case.

The code is now slightly different; commenting it out or removing it still has the same effect: checking out now works on ie.

```
/*
}elseif( $wpsc_checkout->checkout_item->unique_name == 'billingemail'){ ?>
<?php $email_markup =
"<div class='wpsc_email_address'>
<p class='" . wpsc_checkout_form_element_id() . "'>
<label class='wpsc_email_address' for='" . wpsc_checkout_form_element_id() . "'>
" . __('Enter your email address', 'wpsc') . "
</label>
<p class='wpsc_email_address_p'>
<img src='https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/empty?s=60&amp;d=mm' id='wpsc_checkout_gravatar' />
" . wpsc_checkout_form_field();

if(wpsc_the_checkout_item_error() != '')
$email_markup .= "<p class='validation-error'>" . wpsc_the_checkout_item_error() . "</p>";
$email_markup .= "</div>";
*/
```

The IE-problem only occurred when I turned on test-gateway though.